# JavaFX Webview set proxy per instance

Tags: java, javafx, webview, proxy

If I have two different instances of a WebView in JavaFX (either two different window in the same program) or two different instances of a program, is there a way to have each WebView have a different proxy setting without affecting the other or the changing the system settings?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26240059/3605135

You can set a proxy for the whole application only.