# JavaFX WebEngine connection timeout

Tags: https, javafx-webengine

This very simple code:

```
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();
    engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (engine.getLoadWorker().getException() != null && newState == State.FAILED) {
                LogUtil.getLog().error("Fallo al cargar la página", engine.getLoadWorker().getException());
            }
        }
    });
    final String url = webBean.getURL();
    engine.load(url);
```

when loading an URL using https succeeds in JDK1.7.0_80 in a MacOSX, but fails in Windows using the same JDK version. The exception is a 'connection timeout'. The only difference I can see is that the Windows environment uses a proxy, but the same https URL in the same Windows environment and using the same proxy but with an external browser loads without problems too.
I'm really stucked with this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to read up on [Java Networking and Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).  I'm not really an expert in this and cannot advise further.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of: [Set proxy on JavaFX WebEngine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691472/set-proxy-on-javafx-webengine)

Comment: RESOLVED!  We have to set the proxyHost and proxyPort properties for both the http and the https protocols separately. Thanks @jewelsea for the link.